# Iterate over items from a Recator Flux in another Reactor Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have my Flux flux1 and when I iterate over it, I also want to start this Flux again inside of it so I can access all of my items from flux1 while iterating over the items from flux1. Basically doing this but with Flux:

```
for(item in flux1){
  for(item2 in flux1){
  //xxxxx
      }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to have a nested `flatmap`, like this:

```java
Flux<String> flux = Flux.just("a", "b", "c");

flux.flatMap(item -> flux.flatMap(item2 -> 
    doSomethingAsync(item, item2).doOnNext(e -> log.info("doSomethingAsync({}, {});", item, item2))))
```

Prints:

```
 doSomethingAsync(a, a);
 doSomethingAsync(a, b);
 doSomethingAsync(a, c);
 doSomethingAsync(b, a);
 doSomethingAsync(b, b);
 doSomethingAsync(b, c);
 doSomethingAsync(c, a);
 doSomethingAsync(c, b);
 doSomethingAsync(c, c);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Have a nice day!